# While making a simple form, I get a "Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function query()"

Tags: php

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function query() on string in
>    C:\xampp\htdocs\boobae\index.php:58 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in
>
> C:\xampp\htdocs\boobae\index.php on line 58

Here is my code:

```
<?php include './include/header.include.php'; ?>
<?php include './include/connect.include.php';?>
<?php $reg = @$_POST['reg'];

//declaring the variables to prevent errors
$fn = "";
$ln = "";
$un = "";
$em = "";
$em2 = "";
$pswd = "";
$pswd2 = "";
$d_birth = "";
$d = "";
$u_check = "";
$phone_number = "";
$conn="";

//registration form
$fn = strip_tags(@_POST['fname']);
$ln = strip_tags(@_POST['lname']);
$un = strip_tags(@_POST['uname']);
$em = strip_tags(@_POST['email1']);
$em2 = strip_tags(@_POST['email2']);
$pswd = strip_tags(@_POST['passwprd1']);
$pswd2 = strip_tags(@_POST['password2']);
$d_birth = strip_tags(@_POST['dbirth']);
$d = ('Y-M-D');
$phone_number = strip_tags(@_POST['phone_number']);

if  (isset($_POST['reg'])) {
if ($em==$em2) {
}
else {
echo "Your emails do not match!";
}
if ( strlen($un)>25||strlen($fn)>25||strlen($ln)>25) {
echo "The maximum limit for username/first name/last name is 25 characters";
}
if (strlen($pswd)>30||strlen($pswd)<5) {
echo "Your password must be 5 to 30 characters long";
}
if ($fn&&$ln&&$un&&$em&&$em2&&$pswd&&$pswd2) {
}
else{
    echo "Please fill in all the fields!";}
    if ($pswd==$pswd2) {
}
else {
echo "Your pasword do not match!";
}

$sql="INSERT INTO userss (username,first_name,last_name, email, password, 
d_birth, sign_up_date, $phone_number,activated)
VALUES ('$un', '$fn', '$ln', '$em', '$pawd', '$d_birth', '$d',
 '$phone_number')";
//$insert=$con->query($sql);
}

if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
    echo "New record created successfully";
} 
else {
    echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $conn->error;
}

$conn->close();
```

Comment: Show your $conn variable (without the passwords etc ofcourse). It seems that $conn is a connection string, not a SQL connection.

Comment: `$conn="";` pretty obvious that won't work, maybe you're overwriting that variable that's already assigned in `connect.include.php` ?

Answer (score 1):

You set your `$conn="";` right under `$phone_number = "";`. `$conn` needs to be a database connection, not a string

Answer (score 0):

In your current code `$conn="";` which clearly is a string. Make it db connection variable first. Hope this helps.